# Why does my default action method return a 404?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following .NET Core 2.2 API controller

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ExactMatch("id")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }
}
```

And this is my route definition:

```
app.UseMvc(
                routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
                }
                );
        }
```

The following URLs work fine:

```
https://localhost:44305/api/test
https://localhost:44305/api/test/get/5
```

but not this one

```
https://localhost:44305/api/test/5 /* Notice the missing action method*/
```

It returns a 404 error

Could anybody help me figure out what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try the **public class TestController** inherited from **Controller**, not from **ControllerBase** and in the Route, you should specify which controller you are calling, like:
    `routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Test}/{action=Get}/{id?}");`

Comment: Hi Tam, I am trying to create API endpoints not regular  controllers. This would not address my issue

Answer (score 0):

First Replace

```
[ExactMatch("id")]
```

to

```
[HttpGet("id")]
```

Secondly replace

```
app.UseMvc(
                routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
                }
                );
        }
```

to

```
app.UseMvc(
                routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                }
                );
        }
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad,  thanks for the input. I tried it and I am still getting 404 errors

Comment: do you have this on your controller class level.
`["api/{controller}"]`

Comment: Hi Muhammad, No I don't.  I am trying to use convention based routing and avoid attribute routing as much as possible. Less maintenance that way